# MS Query SQL Statement with 2 tables and 3 records

Tags: sql, excel, csv

I have 2 tables. One holds day categories with just these 3 records (shown below `DIS.csv`).  The other contains financial data I want to return (`VAU.csv`).

```
VAU.csv
ID    WORDING  
1     30 - 59 Days  
2     60 - 89 Days  
3     90+  Days
```

I would like 3 records to always be returned even if `60 - 59` is `0`.  The SQL statement below only returns 1 row if only 1 record found. I would like all 3 rows to be returned populated with a count of 0 and a Value of 0, if necessary.

```
SELECT  DIS.DISWORDING, 
        Count(VAU.ITEM), 
        Sum(VAU.VALUE) 

FROM    DIS.csv DIS 
        LEFT JOIN VAU.csv VAU ON DIS.ID = VAU.ID 

WHERE   VAU.TYPE = 'TRADE' 

GROUP   BY DIS.DISWORDING
```

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d005f/16/0

I modified the table names for the sql fiddle.  I think I changed them back correctly....

```
select  dis.diswording, 
        count(vau.item) as item_count, 
        coalesce(sum(vau.value),0) as value_sum

from    dis.csv as dis  

        left join vau.csv as vau 
           on dis.id = vau.id and vau.type = 'trade'  

group   by dis.diswording;
```

You almost had it right.  The condition for `type='trade'` needs to occur in the `join` statement and not down in the `where`.  The `left outer join` says that you want all the rows from `dis.csv` and only rows from `vau.csv` where they match.  It took me a minute to figure it out, but having `type='trade'` in the where was causing some of the data to be lost.

You can also think of it this way:

```
select  dis.diswording, 
        count(vau.item) as item_count, 
        coalesce(sum(vau.value),0) as value_sum

from    dis.csv as dis  

        left join (select *
                   from   vau.csv 
                   where  vau.type = 'trade') as vau 
           on dis.id = vau.id 

group   by dis.diswording;
```

**Edit**:
Instead of `coalesce(sum(vau.value),0) as value_sum` can you try:
[`Nz(sum(vau.value),0) as value_sum`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/nz-function-HA001228890.aspx)

- **Tell me what your exact and full errors are please** (you can update the question).  There are a few ways we can re-write the query so I'm sure it's possible to switch it to something acceptable.  Jet/Excel/Office is a little weird and touchy. I don't have any way I can test these queries in your actual environment before I give them to you.

I'm not sure what part of the query that the DB has issues with.  This also works:
**try replacing coalesce with Nz**

```
select  dis.diswording, 
        sum(case when vau.type='trade' 
                   then 1 else 0 end) as item_count, 
        coalesce(sum(case when vau.type='trade' 
                          then vau.value 
                          else 0 end),0) as value_sum

from    dis.csv as dis  

        left join vau.csv as vau 
           on dis.id = vau.id  

group   by dis.diswording;
```

---

Can you try troubleshooting it to see what part of the query it gives that general error for?  Just make the query as simple as possible by removing parts... then add stuff in.  See if you can isolate the problem.

1. Does this run? (try the most basic form of it)

   ```
     select  dis.id, dis.diswording,
             vau.item, vau.value, vau.type

      from   dis.csv as dis  

             left join vau.csv as vau 
                on dis.id = vau.id
   ```
2. Does this run? (try filtering trade in the join)

   ```
     select  dis.id, dis.diswording,
             vau.item, vau.value, vau.type

      from   dis.csv as dis  

             left join vau.csv as vau 
                on dis.id = vau.id and vau.type='trade'
   ```
3. Does this run? (try the nested select)

   ```
     select  dis.id, dis.diswording,
             vau.item, vau.value, vau.type

      from   dis.csv as dis  

             left join (select * from vau.csv where type='trade') as vau 
                on dis.id = vau.id
   ```
4. Does this run? (assuming #1 worked, add sum/count to a query that works)

   ```
     select  dis.id, dis.diswording,
             count(vau.item) as item_count, 
             sum(vau.value)  as vaue_sum 

      from   dis.csv as dis  

             left join vau.csv as vau 
                on dis.id = vau.id

      group by dis.id, dis.diswording
   ```

And just keep going with that to see what the problem is... slowly build up to the query you want to use.  The general error means we are trying to do something that the DB does not support.  Using a non-existing function will probably be a syntax error.

Comment: Hi there, I really appreciate you taking the time to look at my query. I have tried your suggestions. I either get a Syntax Error or a general ODBC error. I did a few permutations of your examples and found that MSQuery doesn;t seem to like the Coalesce funtion, scouting around i found there was an alternative ISNULL which it still didn;t like (Syntax Error). The second example you gave returned the "General ODBC Error", if i took out the Where Clause from the 2nd example it ran without an error but of course only return a single row.

Comment: Do you think I am trying to achieve something that is impossible with MSQuery (loading data into Excel). Although it does seem a fairly basic request so I would of thought MSQuery would be upto it?. Thanks again, I really do appreciate any help people give.

Comment: tell me what the exact errors are, please... i don't think this is impossible, ms office stuff is kind of weird but there is always a work around.  i don't have the ability to actually test anything in your actual environment, though.  i used the `coalesce` to give me a 0 instead of a null for an empty field.  see if the query runs without that.  if that's the only problem, i'm sure we can find another way to get that zero.

Comment: Try... and use the `Nz` function like this: `Nz(sum(vau.value),0) as value_sum`. Google seems to think it is an equivalent.  Sorry I can't test this myself before suggesting it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks ever so much for your help, in walking through each step you gave I have worked out that in MSQuery you have to use the IIF statement, resulting in the code below. I changed TYPE to CHASSIS and VALUE to SIV but only to make the database easier to read. Again I really appreciate people like yourself helping strangers when it is so easy to click on the next page.

"SELECT DIS.DISWORDING, COUNT(VAU.CHASSIS), IIF(SUM(VAU.SIV) IS NULL, 0, SUM(VAU.SIV)) AS SUM FROM DIS.csv AS DIS LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM  VAU.csv AS VAU WHERE VAU.VEHICLETYPE ='TRADE') AS VAU ON DIS.DISID = VAU.DISID GROUP BY DIS.DISID, DIS.DISWORDING"

BTW Just read your home page, really sorry to hear of recent events. Stay ahead of the game and be there for all around you...Cheers